# value weighted "xtile" does not give close to equal division (Stata)

Tags: stata

I'm using the following Stata code to calculate value weighted (`wt`) groups based on a variable called `x`:

> egen q = xtile(x), by(year) nq(2) weights(wt)

However, the code above gives me very unequal groups, something like:
`Group1: 1000; Group2: 100`

I couldn't find the help file on how the weight is used when calculating these groups. So I'm confused why this happens (my `x` variable is continuous and is unlikely to have equal values across observations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `egen` function is from the `egenmore` package on SSC. A quick look at the code would show you that `_pctile` is being called for each group with the weights specified as analytic weights.

Despite what you say, unequal groups are common as a result, typically because of tied values or very unequal weights. For some general discussion, see Section 4 of [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200413) and Section 6 of [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1801800311)

Nothing more can be said about your dataset because you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you. After I tried a few makeup datasets, I realize that I misunderstood how value-weighted groups are generated.